# Lua loading .dylib: "Symbol not found", although it exists

Tags: c++, macos, lua, dynamic-linking, luajit

I have a `libSoapySDR.dylib` on MacOS (10.12.6, clang-802.0.42) I would like to load with [LuaJIT FFI](https://luajit.org/).

The library compiles and links just fine and produces the `.dylib` without errors.

However, when I `ffi.load('libSoapySDR.dylib')` I receive:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __Z10getEnvImplPKc
  Referenced from: libSoapySDR.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __Z10getEnvImplPKc
  Referenced from: libSoapySDR.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

The funny part is:

- The C++ funtion `getEnvImpl()` ([C++ source](https://github.com/pothosware/SoapySDR/blob/master/lib/Modules.in.cpp)) is only used
  internally, within the `.dylib`.
- Lua does not try to access it ([Lua
  source](https://github.com/vsergeev/luaradio/blob/master/radio/blocks/sources/soapysdr.lua)).
- If I `inline` the function, `ffi.load` seems to work.
- If I `nm -g ./libSoapySDR.dylib`, I can see the output

  `000000000000b3b0 T __Z10getEnvImplPKc`

So, it seems to be *there*, but `ffi.load()` still fails, claiming it were not.

**Can someone explain what is going on?**

I would very much like not to inline the code, as it is not my code base, and I'm not sure that I fully understand the situation (nor that I would be allowed to submit a patch the first place).

Comment: I still do not understand my problem, but if I load the lib with `ffi.load(..., true)`, it works ...